# How can I set the kerning on just one combination of characters in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, typography, kerning

I'm using a font in my app that results in terrible kerning whenever a 4 appears after a .

In a dynamic UI label that sometimes shows the .4, is it possible to programmatically increase the kerning *only if* those characters show up side by side?

[image: normal kerning]

[image: bad combo]

Comment: Use a better-kerned font, instead of adjusting poorly kerned pairs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are so inclined, you can try to parse the [Kern Table](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6kern.html) and perhaps modify the `UIFont` / `CFFont` to suit your needs. I'm not a font designer so I'll just add an observer to the label and watch if `.4` occurs to apply kerning.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.label.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: [.New], context: nil)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if object === self.label,
        let change = change,
        let newValue = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? NSString,
        let attributedText = self.label.attributedText?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString {

        let matchRange = newValue.rangeOfString(".4")
        if matchRange.location == NSNotFound {
            attributedText.removeAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, range: NSMakeRange(0, newValue.length))
        } else {
            let kernRange = NSMakeRange(matchRange.location, matchRange.length - 1)
            attributedText.setAttributes([NSKernAttributeName: 10], range: kernRange)
        }

        self.label.attributedText = attributedText
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - i'm a newbie so i wasn't able to get this working in my setup, but I have a feeling others would be successful.  thanks again